# Touch gestures support of WinForms controls in WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms, touch, webbrowser-control, multi-touch

There are two versions of WebBrowser control (WinForms and WPF). WPF version supports touch and multitouch gestures. Does WinForms version of WebBrowser embedded in WPF application with WindowsFormsHost support touch and multi-touch gestures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the WebBrowserControl regardless of how it is hosted. It will still get touch and multi-touch gestures as long as its the only thing getting the input and the touch is from a recognised touch device to Windows.

Note you can't quite hook into this nor can you touch outside and inside the WebBrowserControl as it runs in a different context similar to running in a different window

Also for what its worth the underlying ActiveX Host is just running an Internet Explorer frame. If you have IE8 or more recent (such as assuming windows 7 or 8 for you?) it will run it in IE7 Compatibility mode too.